# How do I bundle several units of 3G modems to improve bandwidth?

Tags: 12.04, networking, internet, usb-modem, macbook-pro

How do I bundle let's say five to ten units of 3G modems in order to improve the download speed? I'd like to do this on Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS.

In the end, I would like to use the Ubuntu server as an Internet gateway and connect a Macbook Pro via Wireless LAN.

It would also be nice if the MacBook can do load balancing between WiFI and USB modem directly connected.

Please, also recommend the USB modem models as well as the line binding scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to use some proxy with load-balancing capabilities. `Squid` is a default, if awkward, choice. However, explaining how to configure it is more than a paragraph or two. So read manuals and apply head. 
This will improve the speed of simultaneous access to different files. To improve the speed of downloading single file, you will have to add the use of some downloader, like `KGet`, and no proof it will work. So don't expect it.